# To what extent have black project programs taken, computers, lasers and robots?

Tags: politics

What we are allowed go see technologically is minimal compared to what must exist in secret.  Knowing that other, less ideologically peacefull countries are working feverishly on similar technologys, we must have persued these subjects with the same investments as the Manhattan Project.  Could it be otherwise?  I believe it would be irresponsible not to do so. What do you think?

Comment: Hello, Chris Montgomery! Welcome to Worldbuilding. Your question does not seem to be about worldbuilding as it's defined in the [Help Center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help), and it's asking for an opinion about whether we should care about secret technology, which also makes this subject to be closed for being primarily opinion-based and hard to empirically validate for the purpose of a good answer. Might I suggest editing your question to be about specific secret technology and how it might affect warfare or specific segments of society? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The military officially shot down by missile with a laser weapon back in 2001. It's a matter of public record that this happened. Should probably find out more about it on line. It is also public knowledge that the military has been experimenting with prototype War robots to be introduced into the military. Technically all these things are matter of publicly record, so technically the government is not trying to keep them Secret but most people don't know about them.

Comment: Unofficially, the Russians have been zapping spy satellites with their lasers for a decade or more.  Also military secret programs are not black holes.  That information always leaks out eventually.